# Visual Studio 2013/2015 - node package build error (gulp_util)

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, gulp

A little background:

My team has a web branding project in Visual Studio, just static HTML, CSS and a little javascript - no .NET classes or anything.

We added node, npm, gulp and some gulp task packages to take care of some bundling and minification.

The gulp tasks run fine via the Task Runner Explorer, no issues.

However, some of our team are getting an error when attempting to build the project (in order to view the static pages in browsers through IIS):

> Error      13           The command ""C:\TFS\Branding\packages\Gulp.js.1.0.2\build..\tools\npm.cmd" install gulp gulp-util --save-dev" exited with code 1.    Branding

I have not been able to determine why this is occuring or why it only happens for some of the team. We are using a mixture of VS2013 and 2015, but the error can occur on either.

I can see that the command in question does exist at the location - on one of the affected environments, if I run:

```
npm install gulp gulp-util --save-dev
```

from the command prompt in the project root - it installs without error, yet the VS project still produces the error.

I'm stumped, and any ideas on what to look into would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your location "C:\TFS\Branding\packages\Gulp.js.1.0.2\build..\tools\npm.cmd" tells me that this is installed with nuget (because of the packages folder). You should not use nuget if you only do client side developing, use npm and bower instead - especially there is good support now in VS 2013 and 2015.

Comment: I did indeed use nuget. It's rare for us to have a client-side only solution. I'll try getting rid of it and using bower instead

Comment: @LiviuCostea - removing all traces of nuget did the trick - you should add this as an answer so I can accept it!

Comment: full text of error for search keywords: 
`2>  File Not Found
2>  '"C:\Source\ProjectName\packages\Npm.js.1.3.15.7\tools\..\..\\node.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
2>  operable program or batch file.
2>C:\Source\ProjectName\packages\Gulp.js.1.0.2\build\gulp.js.targets(12,3): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\ProjectName\packages\Gulp.js.1.0.2\build\..\tools\npm.cmd" install gulp gulp-util --save-dev" exited with code 1.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your location "C:\TFS\Branding\packages\Gulp.js.1.0.2\build..\tools\npm.cmd" tells me that this is installed with nuget (because of the packages folder). You should not use nuget if you only do client side developing, use npm and bower instead - especially there is good support now in VS 2013 and 2015.

Comment: Removing nuget packages completely and using npm only made this error go away, thank you

Comment: We're also getting this error on each new development station where we clone the project. Removing all use of nuget is not currently an option, so I'll have to find another way to do this. Can you give any insight as to why the above solution "fixes" the problem? It might help me find a nuget compatible solution.

Comment: and how is npm supposed to get packages without node.js to bootstrap? isn't npm dependent on node?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. There is a build task in the gulp package. We added the gulp directory under "SolutionName"\node_modules\gulp to solve this

Comment: I don't fully understand... we have a gulp directory inside ..\node_modules - but there is also a Gulp.js.1.0.2 folder inside the ..\packages folder. Is this second one the one that needs moving?

Comment: Copying the Node.js.0.10.21 folder from a successfully building workstation to the SolutionFolder/packages directory gets my builds running on each workstation where I clone my project. The question I have is, how is this development dependency *supposed* to get into the packages folder? I can't find a corresponding nuget package online.

Comment: I take that back. There is a node.js nuget package, and it solved my problem. Unfortunately it drops files I don't need in my project, since it's a dev-only dependency.

Comment: We've come to the realisation in my team that we need to use different package managers for different types of projects - nuget for .NET packages, bower for javascript and css packages, and npm for anything that needs node, like gulp. We install node.js separately, not through nuget.

Comment: Starscream, how do you bootstrap npm into your development projects? Does it require an additional step after checking out your project? It's important to me that my projects build immediately after checkout, without any additional steps, and I prefer not to check in 3rd party elements of our toolchain.