# How can I deploy a Durandal application using visual studio 2015?

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2015, durandal

I have a [Durandal](http://durandaljs.com/) application created in Visual Studio 2015, using mvc and ef6.  When I deploy the project to the web, Visual Studio takes care of the bundling of the various js and css files, but not of those that Durandal is using, nor the view and viewmodel files I created in the app.

In the Durandal site there's a short [explanation](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Automating-Builds-with-Visual-Studio.html) on how to do this; however, it is very minimal, and I cannot find a way to create the 'main-built.js' file described there. I followed the instructions of installing gulp and adding 'gulp build' command to the Build Events, but when I try to build the project it seems that 'gulp' cannot be found.

Can someone please provide a more detailed explanation on how to deploy a Durandal application using Visual Studio 2015?

Comment: Is the "nodejs" on your system installed?

Comment: Create a new project in visual studio. then add "durandal" to your project. now run the "optimizer" and see results. is it works fine? ("main-buit.js" is created in "App" folder?)

Comment: I installed nodejs; but I cannot find the optimizer, where is it?...

Comment: So which version of durandal you use?

Comment: the latest, version 2.1

Answer (score 1):

1- Make sure that "nodejs" has been installed on your system.

2- Create a new empty web project in your vs2015.

3- Add "HotTowel: ASP.NET MVC SPA Template" with nuget package manager.

- If you use "durandal 1.x" run optimizer from : "~\App\durandal\amd\" folder. (run it from a separate command prompt window is better solution)
- If you use "durandal 2.x" follow this steps:

  1- Install Gulp or Grunt via Nuget Package Manager.

  2- Add a config file in the project root to create your "built config file" ([Gulp](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Gulp.html) or [Grunt](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Grunt.html) ...)

  3- For automating builds with vs, [follow this](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Automating-Builds-with-Visual-Studio.html)

**If there is no error in the application ('javascript code'), even a bit !, it runs correctly.**

Comment: Thanks for your help :-).  When I try to install 'gulp' via npm I get the following error: "Severity Code Description Project File Line
Error  Could not install package 'Node.js 0.10.21'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0
"

Comment: Your welcome;) I install the 'gulp' package correctly,but I'm using the visual studio 2013.
you can copy required package manually to your solution packages folder as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31968608/visual-studio-2013-2015-node-package-build-error-gulp-util) or try to install another version of node to resolve your problem: 

get a list of available package: Get-Package -ListAvailable -Filter Node.js -AllVersions

, and install specific version of node: Install-Package Node.js -Version 0.10.28

Comment: [This help](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx) may also be useful

Comment: Thanks!  I'l go through it and report back :-)

Comment: First I want to thank you again.  Thanks to your link above ("this help") I managed to get the 'all.min.js' file built as part of the build process in VS.  However I get js errors when I try to browse the index file which links to 'all.min.js', starting with: 'Mismatched anonymous define() module'.  I thought this might have to do with the fact that not all the js files combined into 'all.min.js' are in the same directory, some are under 'app' and some under 'scripts' (the durandal ones) but even when I moved the durandal folder to 'app' I still got the same error... any idea?  Thank you.

Comment: Your welcome;) , congratulations!
You use the c#.net mvc index razor view,right? , and your app runs correctly in debugging mode, don't you?
Maybe some of the required js files not loaded in your index page when you are defined your modules. Can you send your main index page code?

Comment: Yes :-)  I'll be happy to send you the file, how would you like me to do that please (i.e. via email or another way...).  Thanks!

Comment: ok ,sure! . You can write your code here or send me to check it: ab.mousavi.p@gmail.com

Comment: Thanks!!  I want to share the code so that others will learn from it, but it is not short enough for here; I'll send it to you and then share the bottom line with everyone back here so that it will hopefully help others too.